# How to find out which extension provided the command in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm clueless what feature came out of which extension, is there a way to have its source displayed?

Also would be interesteed to know if its possible to trace the source code of the features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is checking the `package.json` files, as even [`vscode.commands.getCommands()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands.getCommands) only returns plain strings. This can be done with the [`vscode.extensions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#extensions) API:

```ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        for (const extension of vscode.extensions.all) {
            let commands = extension.packageJSON.contributes?.commands;
            if (!Array.isArray(commands)) {
                continue;
            }
            for (const command of commands) {
                console.log(command.title + " is from " + extension.id);
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Note that `all` only includes *activated* extensions, hence the timeout to make sure all extensions that activate on startup are done with their activation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> what feature came out of which extension

Yes, you can do this, taking advantage of VSC's intellisense:

- I'm Assuming (1) by feature, you mean a command executable from the command pallette and
- Open `keybindings.json` in vscode
- You should see JSON like below; if not, add one like below (you're not going to keep it).

```
  {
    "key": ".",
    "command": "REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR COMMAND NAME",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible"
  }
```

- Where it says "REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR COMMAND NAME", begin typing the name of the command you're interested in
- The VSC suggestion widget will open, showing roughly `EXTENSION_NAME.YOUR_COMMAND`.  If the suggest widget doesn't open, press `ctrl+space` to open it.
- Note the name of the extension; that's what contributed that feature/command.  If the name doesn't match an extension, it's probably a core VSC feature

> trace the source code of the features

- Most extensions are on GitHub, as is the core code for VSC, so you can simply navigate to the relevant repository and seacrch the code for that command.

Comment: no, the command ID's prefix part is not necessarily the extension's ID or name. It can give you a good hint as to which extension it is though.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery) out from VS Code documentation.

Here you can see where the extensions are installed by default.

And further, you can access their source code.

> **Where are extensions installed?**
>
> Extensions are installed in a per user extensions folder. Depending on your platform, the location is in the following folder:
>
> - **Windows** `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
> - **macOS** `~/.vscode/extensions`
> - **Linux** `~/.vscode/extensions`
>
> You can change the location by launching VS Code with the --extensions-dir  command-line option

About which feature cames from which extension, I'm not sure if it's possible to achive that.

Comment: And also most of the extensions have a link to their repository where you can see the source code...

Answer (score 0):

Click on an extension and in the editor that opens showing its `readme`, click on the `Feature Contributions` link and you'll see the settings and commands that extension contributes.  For example:

[image: extension features demo]

Answer (score 0):

Open the Keyboard Shortcut editor (you can run `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)). Search for the command of interest. There'll be a column showing the source of the command. If the command comes from an extension, it'll show the extension name as a link that you can click on to navigate to the extension's page.

Mark's answer also works, but with that way, you have to guess extensions and  read through the list of contributed commands to see if it's the right one. With the keyboard Shortcut editor, you can just search.