# Determine what registered a vscode extension property

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This is not a duplicate of [How to find out which extension provided the command in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281712) because commands are not properties. The answer to it may form the basis of a diagnostic extension. If it does, I will publish it and answer my own question with a referral to the tool. If you close this issue I won't be able to do that and you will prevent people from finding a useful answer.

When a VS Code extension is loaded, properties defined in its `package.json` are registered.

Property names must be globally unique. Two extensions cannot register `book.paperSize`.

I would like to determine the origin of a property. Apart from anything else, I suspect in this case it is a remnant of an earlier unfinished project, but things are confused by the fact that I don't see it in the installed extensions list and adding `--disable-extensions` to the launch arguments for the extension development host doesn't make the error go away.

How can I determine the registrant of an already registered extension property?

An answer that adds code to an extension is fine. Or anything else.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "property here"? do you mean configuration/settings properties? Why can't you just grep through the package.json files of your `~/.vscode/extensions` folder? Also, is this a question about extension _development_? Because that's what the vscode-extensions tag is for.

Comment: @starball `grep` is a Unix thing, I already did that using alternate means, and of course it's a question about extension development, that's why the `vscode-extensions` tag was already assigned when you wrote. The `book.paperSize` thing makes no sense, I can't find it anywhere. And now I have an extension contributed command that asks for a string and returns all the properties that start with it along with the contributing extension.

Answer (score 0):

OK as promised in the question I put together a command that dumps properties and their contributors, and another one for dumping commands and their contributors as per the related question.

[image: Dump commands]

Both prompt for the start of the property name you're tracking down.

[image: Prompt for start of name]

In my case I searched for "book". Look what turned up.

[image: The embarrassing truth]

Searching in `package.json` reveals that *someone* changed the title but not the property name when copy/pasting. Embarrassing but now I know with certainty where to look and what to look for, and this has happened before when it *wasn't* my goof, so I'm pleased to have the dump commands.

These commands are present on the Marketplace in the [Print extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pdconsec.vscode-print). At the moment they don't handle an unsupplied string correctly but I'll fix that in a later release.

Output goes to the console, which means you need to run an extension in the debug host to see it. The next iteration will create a new document in the editor to relax this restriction.